# Angular 2: error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null' In loading PDF file

Tags: angular

my problem consist in a table with different rows, each one you click and will load a different PDF file, my logic consist in load the PDF in a `ember` or `iframe`, for example:

```
<iframe class="center-block" [src]="ruta" width="80%" height="90%"></iframe>
```

but with that I'm getting this error:

```
error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64523:16)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64501:29)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:33235:31)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:479:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:453:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:479:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:453:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:479:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:453:18)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:479:26)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:131_loop_1 @ zone.js:412drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:421
error_handler.js:52 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:131_loop_1 @ zone.js:412drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:421
error_handler.js:53 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (apply_redirects.js:89)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (apply_redirects.js:67)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:52)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:468)
    at zone.js:445
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:232)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.js:236)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:231)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:114)
    at zone.js:502
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:265)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:227)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:264)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:53next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:131_loop_1 @ zone.js:412drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:421
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'(…) Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64523:16)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64501:29)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:33235:31)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:479:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:453:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:479:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:453:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:479:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:453:18)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:479:26)consoleError @ zone.js:388_loop_1 @ zone.js:417drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:421
zone.js:390 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'(…)consoleError @ zone.js:390_loop_1 @ zone.js:417drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:421
expedientes.component.ts:64 [Object]
```

I suppose (I don't know) I'm getting that error because at the start `route` has `null` value because you get the value after you click the link in the row of the table. I already tried to use `ngIf` just to show that `iframe` when route have value different than `null` but did't work

```
<iframe *ngIf="ruta!=null" class="center-block" [src]="ruta" width="80%" height="90%"></iframe>
```

I'll show my code if anyone can help me.

HTML:

```
<div class="">
  <section class="content-wrap">
    <table class="table table-fixed table-responsive table-striped barraTitulo">
      <thead class="container">
        <tr class="menu row">
          <th class="col-xs-2 text-center">Registro</th>
          <th class="col-xs-2 text-center">Descripcion</th>
          <th class="col-xs-4 text-center">Nombre</th>
          <th class="col-xs-2 text-center">Fecha</th>
          <th class="col-xs-2 text-center">Opciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="container">
        <tr *ngFor="let doc of documentos.Archivo.Documentos" (click)="estilos();" class="row">
          <!-- <label for="">{{doc}}</label> -->
          <td class="col-xs-2 text-center" (click)="estilos();"><label>{{doc.descripcion}}</label></td>
          <td class="col-xs-2 text-center" (click)="estilos();" ><label>{{doc.crDigitalizacion}}</label></td>
          <td *ngIf="doc.extension=='PDF'"  class="col-xs-4 text-center pdf" (click)="estilos();"><label>{{doc.nombre}} PDF</label></td>
          <td *ngIf="doc.extension!='PDF'"  class="col-xs-4 text-center imagen" (click)="estilos();"><label>{{doc.nombre}} img</label></td>
          <td class="col-xs-2 text-center"><label>{{doc.fecha}}</label></td>
          <td class="col-xs-2 text-center">
            <img alt="Descargar" title="Descargar" src="/shared/images/download.png">
            <img alt="Adjuntar Documento" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#subirImagen" title="Adjuntar Documento" src="/shared/images/upload.png">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>

  <section [class.showing]="classVisible"  class="archivoPDF side side-A ">

      <iframe *ngIf="ruta!=null" class="center-block" [src]="ruta" width="80%" height="90%"></iframe>

  </section>

  <section [class.showing]="classVisible"  class="archivoIMG side side-B ">
    <iframe class="center-block" [src]="ruta" width="80%" height="90%"></iframe>
  </section>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Expediente } from "../../interfaces/expedientes";
import { DocService } from "../../services/documento.service";
import { Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-docs',
  templateUrl: './docs.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['./docs.component.css'],
  providers:  [DocService]
})
export class DocsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('documentos') documentos1: Expediente
  public documentos :Expediente

  constructor(private router: Router, private _httpService: DocService) { }
  ruta: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ruta = null;
    this.documentos ={
      id:                  null,
      folioExpediente:     null,
      idCliente:           null,
      Cliente:    {
        id:                null,
        nombre:            null,
        codigoCliente:     null
      },
      Archivo:    {
        id:                null,
        idExpediente:      null,
        registro:          null,
        clave:             null,
        folio:             null,
        fecha:             null,
        Documentos: [{
          id:              null,
          idArchivo:       null,
          crDigitalizacion:null,
          tipo:            null,
          descripcion:     null,
          extension:       null,
          fecha:           null,
          nombre:          null,
          numeroPaginas:   null,
          tamanoArchivo:   null
        }]
      }
    };
    console.log(this.documentos + "Inicio Docs")
  }
  ngOnChanges(){
    if(this.documentos1!=null){
      this.documentos=this.documentos1
    }
  }

classVisible: boolean = false
showDiv:  boolean = false


estilos() {
  if(this.classVisible == true)  {
    this.classVisible = false;
    this.showDiv = false
  } else {
    this.classVisible = true;
    this.showDiv = true;
  }
}

}
```

I declared `ruta` with null because I wanted to change that value after when I had the row value but did't work